# How to handle large columnar data files in Octave WITH headers?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a .dat file that is space/tab delimited with 1 line of headers. There are about 60 columns of data in this file. There are others with other numbers of columns.

How can I read in the headers (as a vector, perhaps?) such that I can index into the appropriate column of the data-matrix without having to count my way manually to the correct column?

I seem to recall Matlab being able to create cell-arrays with headers as indexes. Is anything like that remotely possible in Octave?

So far, all I can get is the actual data according to this:

```
a = dlmread('Core.dat'," ",r0=1,c0=0);
```

Any and all help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an easy way to do this using just the standard packages, also, but there doesn't seem to be one.

However, it does look like the [dataframe package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/dataframe/index.html), might let you do this sort of thing.

It does seem like something simpler should be built into the language, though.